# SQL alocar registro (RowLock)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e estou enfrentando um problema sobre concorrência dos registros.

Oque acontece é que tenho varias pessoas que podem acessar o mesmo registro, então precisava que quando um usuário clicar em editar, eu aloca-se esse registro.

Pesquisando vi que existe um `rowlock` mas não estou conseguindo, mesmo colocando esse parâmetro, ainda assim consigo alterar a linha.

No exemplo abaixo, quero bloquear a linha cuja `id` corresponde a 1099, porém mesmo efetuando isso, se eu executar um `UPDATE` ele executa com sucesso.

```
SELECT * FROM crm_man WITH (holdlock,rowlock)
WHERE id = 1099
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando trabalhamos com `lock's` precisamos explicitar o inicio do comando e o fim:

```
begin tran //inicio do comando

select * from crm_man with (holdlock,rowlock)
where id = 1099    

commit // fim do comando
```

no caso acima, em quanto nao for executado o comando `commit` o lock estará ativo, e nenhum update ou alteração da linha será executado.